Someone stole my phone and manage my account through Google it
My Gmail account was hacked. And everytime I create a new account it was always been hacked. I just saw odd Google app in my. Like accounts.google.com and Google it thing. So I assume my someone stole my Gmail account to navigate and control how I should use it and my way of logging in. I need help. I really do not know what to do. There are important files stored in my drive. How to recover my account.
